# can't change variable by using jquery.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change `var code` value to `"asd"` if data output is true but it is not working.

**current result**

[image]

**jquery code** :

```
$('.generate').click(function() {
      var code = "vhe8t";

      $.post('functions/functions.php', {
        fun: "code_generate",
        string: code
      }, function(data) {
        if (data == "true") {
          code = "asd";
          console.log("hello world");
        }
      })

     console.log(code);
});
```

**Function.php code**

```
<?php

  $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "shop_management");

  $fun = "";
  if (isset($_POST['fun'])) {
    $fun = $_POST['fun'];
  }

  if ($fun == "code_generate") {
    $code = $_POST['string'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM code WHERE code='$code'";
    $run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $nums = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if ($nums > 0) {
      echo 'true';
    } else {
      echo 'false';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Async problem! this is duplicated for sure.

Comment: The `console.log()` is being executed before the `$.post()` has complete as **Ele** has pointed out *"Async problem"*. If you can to update the `code` variable then you should define it in the global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.post` runs asynchronously. When that function is run, it only sends out the request - the response hasn't come back yet, so when you run `console.log(code);`, `code` still hasn't changed during that 1ms.

Put it in the callback instead:

```
$.post('functions/functions.php', {
  fun: "code_generate",
  string: code
}, function(data) {
  if (data == "true") {
    code = "asd";
    console.log("hello world");
    console.log(code);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a duplicated question my friend `:)`

Comment: this will give me console output. I want to change the variable.

Comment: It does change the variable: `code = "asd";`

Comment: @saqibkifayat As posted in my comment below your question. *"define `code`  in the global scope`"*